# Jmeter is running multiple instance of Getstatus service with different response times

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

I am currently working on an Application, in which Clicking "Submit" is the last action to be performed by the user. Once it is clicked, there is a loading screen being displayed and it triggers a "get status" service which waits on a callback to understand whether the transaction is success or not. It keeps triggering this service at an interval of 5 seconds until the callback is received from the Middleware on the transaction status (Whether its success or not).

My issue here is, I am unable to figure out the overall response time of the application. Since there are multiple instances of this service with different response time. Please help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put your GetStatus request under the [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/while-controller-jmeter) and come up with a [function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) which will break the while loop when transaction outcome will be available
2. Put the whole construction under the [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller), it will measure the cumulative execution time and will exclude these 5 seconds sleep times between GetStatus calls

[image]